# valid version of connect with node v0.8.1

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use connect v2.3.5 with node 0.8.1 - does anyone know whether this is stable (I am also using express v2.5.11 on Ubuntu 11).  I can move to an older version of connect that would work with node 0.8.1 and express 2.5.11 as long as I know the cutoff connect version.

Comment: moved to older version of connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved to older version of connect - v1.8.5 & I am not experiencing the issue with path/fs I was experiencing earlier.